# Horizontal ScrollView in iPhone

Tags: uiview

I would like to build an iPhone App that uses a horizontal scroll similar to this:

[image]
<sub>(source: [tappgala.com](http://www.tappgala.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/11/weather4.jpg))</sub>

Do i have to use a UIScrollView and work on it, are there some UI Components that make this job or are there better ways to obtain the result?

Answer (score 0):

Touch-based scrolling behaviour is best achieved with a `UIScrollView`, but if you only want to switch between pages of content in response to taps (i. e. what a `UITabViewController` does) then you're perfectly fine with programmatically swapping views.

Comment: well, i would like to horizontal scroll and, when selected, change the detail content without changing page.

Comment: Your description still is unclear to me. You might want to update your question above with a little more information: What area would you like to scroll? Where would the user make a selection and which part do you consider the detail content? And what do you mean by “without changing page”? Creating two or three images that show the state changes and highlighting the areas you’re referring to would make this clearer.